# Calculating string from a text box with operator precedence

Tags: c#, visual-studio, calculator

Button code:
All the code in my button does is populate the text box with a string representation of the number.

```
    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((screenBox.Text == "0") || (opr))
        {
            screenBox.Clear();

        }
        opr = false;
        screenBox.Text = screenBox.Text + button9.Text;
    }
```

Operator code:
Operator code does the exact same thing.

```
    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        operation = buttonAdd.Text;
        screenBox.Text =screenBox.Text +" "+ operation +" ";

    }
```

Equals:
Now, when I press equals.

```
    public void buttonEq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        operation = buttonEq.Text;
        screenBox.Text = " " + screenBox.Text + " " + operation;

        string splitUp;  //stores elements of the original string
        string expr = screenBox.Text;   //makes expr whatever is in textbox

        string[] ops;//makes array called ops

        ops = expr.Split( '(', ')', '^', '/', '*', '+', '-', '='); 
        //splits expr which contains the string input to the screenbox                             
        //using any operator as a token (unless i'm confused and you don't  
        //all them tokens with this method) 

        foreach(string op in ops)
        {
            splitUp = op;
            Console.WriteLine(op);
        }
        //string split up holds whatever is in op, which is a string that  
        //contains an element of ops, which is the array that indexes the  
        //elements of the original string
        //eg 5+5= in the text box would appear as        in the console.                      
                                                //5 
                                                //5
```

How should I be tackling this now so that my program understands that it has split on an add, so it needs to add the two numbers before and after that + (or '*', '/', '-') but to check for "(" ")" brackets on the right of the operator before performing calculation and collecting the sum of that sequence first sort of thing

I just want the basic  of what sort of logic I should be going with.

Comment: Better use an Expression Parser than building your own. [Search for C# Expression parser](http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20expression%20parser&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=c%23%20expression%20parser&sc=3-20&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=aef9e3e63ef24f1aa2db073cb00d0e29)

Comment: I know but this is work for college I don't think we can include a library. Been looking around as to what sort of logic to implement but haven't really gotten far...still, early days.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I am kind of disappointed with being told to just include a library rather than experience the learning curve of creating my own parser.

So. It is long and I have by no means got an advanced parser, but it does basic things so far like operate on numbers in a precedence sequence that I set etc.

So I won't go into detail but basically I will say what would have been helpful for me to know.

1. Prepare
   You will need basic understanding of Stacks, Queues, Lists, Arrays and search on how to build a Tokenization class (for this class, you are going to need to understand Enums "Token"  Data type and get functions too )You will need to research "Shunting Yard Algorithm" and "Reverse Polish Notation" & how to incorporate in programming HEAVILY
2. Build Tokenization class
   Once you have understood how to effectively Tokenize a string, that is, take a string of input and either edit it to contain the appropriate Tokens, or implement a technique where tokens are automatically a part of input and minimal edits to the original string is required. You should research on how to build a good Tokenization class. and attempt it.

2.5: No errors = Continue

3.Shunting Yard and Reverse polish notation will be implemented by using elements and datatypes from the Tokenization class as well as step 1 but from the form class.

Tokenization class will contain all information for things like precedence associatvity etc.

4.if your Shunting yard Algorithm is implemented successfully in your form class, you can then incorporate reverse polish notation to the operators and operands that have been output in by the Shunting Yard Algorithm

I am a newbie, so sorry I can't explain in detail or if I have made a mistake please highlight and correct me!